# CMake fails to link parts of the standard library but manual compilation works just fine

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, g++, linker-errors

I am having an issue building a project with CMake. I have narrowed down the issue and recreated it in a single .cpp file. This issue all started when I was trying to link a project against GTest.
I understand that `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()` is not something I would typically call, the error posted below is the same one I receive when I add a TEST block to my code. I can pull all the GTest files into my project just fine with CMake's fetchcontent but when I actually try to include a TEST block in any .cpp file I get the error below.
Compiling the single .cpp file with g++ directly works just fine. I am able to build and run the output with the expected results. However, using CMake I receive a linker error.

The cpp file.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()
}
```

When I compile manually this is my result:

```
$ g++ main.cpp 
$ ./a.out
Hello World
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
  what():  std::bad_array_new_length
Aborted (core dumped)
```

--edit
Output of g++ --version

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

--

Which is, of course, what I would expect. However, running this against CMake results in the following.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(TestProject CXX)

add_executable(MainTest main.cpp)
```

Output:

```
build$ cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: build

build$ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MainTest.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable MainTest
CMakeFiles/MainTest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x1f): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/MainTest.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'MainTest' failed
make[2]: *** [MainTest] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MainTest.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MainTest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Both of these are compiled with g++ 11.1

---

File structure just in case

ProjectDir
| CMakeLists.txt
| main.cpp
| build

Comment: "Both of these are compiled with g++ 11.1" - Are you sure about that? CMake uses compiler at `/usr/bin/g++` which it treats as GNU 11.1.0. But what `g++` refers to in non-CMake case? E.g. what is output of `g++ --version`?

Comment: Searching for the error message gives e.g. [that bugreport](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/40703), according to which the error is specific for gcc 11.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Added an edit to show version. Also I saw that when I was googling the problem. I still get the same results if I switch to clang. It is almost as if CMake isn't pointing to the correct standard library.

Comment: CMake just emits the command line for the compiler and linker. BTW, you can inspect these command lines by using `make V=1` and compare with the manual one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the generated make files, it seems that CMake was populating a lot of linker and compiler flags, many of which were not needed or simply just wrong. Manually setting the linker and compiler flags inside of CMake has resolved this issue.